# Subject.OnError throwing

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm using Rx .NET's `Subject.OnError` and it seems to be throwing rather than propagating the exception. My scenario is that the Subject is fed data on a separate thread, and the calling thread needs to do stuff when that data is returned, and also await the completion of all data from the observable, as well as propagating up any exceptions that occur.

Here is a simplified example:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subject = new Subject<bool>();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            subject.OnError(new Exception()); //This call is throwing!
        });

        subject.Subscribe(e =>
        {
            //Do some data processing here
        });

        try
        {
            //Need to wait for observable to complete before returning to the caller
            await subject.LastOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            //Do some logging, clean up resources
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the call to `subject.Subscribe()` the code works as you'd expect and the exception is rethrown at `subject.LastOrDefaultAsync()`. However, with `Subscribe` present the call to `subject.OnError()` is immediately rethrowing the exception in place (not passing it to the observable), which seems completely bizarre to me.

How do I resolve this issue?

(FYI, a ton of code is already written using `Subject`, so suggesting that I not use it at all isn't an acceptable solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simpler example:

```
void Main()
{
    var subject = new Subject<bool>();
    subject.Subscribe(b => {/* bool handling code */});
    subject.OnError(new Exception()); //This call is throwing!
}
```

That `Subscribe` overload re-throws exceptions it receives. If you want to ignore the exceptions, then do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var subject = new Subject<bool>();
    // subject.Subscribe();
    subject.Subscribe(b => {/* bool handling code */}, e => { });
    subject.OnError(new Exception()); //This call is throwing!

}
```

If you want to see this source, look here: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Observable.Extensions.cs (line 63). It throws any caught exceptions.

---

**EDIT**:

If you want to dive into the rabbit hole, here's (effectively) the exception handling code that ends up getting called with the `.Subscribe(onNextHandlerOnly)` overload:

```
void Main()
{
    var subject = new Subject<bool>();
    subject.Subscribe(b => b.Dump(), e => { e.Throw(); }, () => {});
    subject.OnError(new Exception()); //This call is throwing!

}

public static class X
{
    public static void Throw(this Exception exception)
    {
         System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
    }
}
```

The `EDI.Capture` call makes it look like the 'source' of the exception is the `OnError` call, and not the `Subscribe`.

Comment: Thanks, this fix works, although I do not understand this design at all. It seems like a call to `Subscribe` mutating the observable in some way is the antithesis of functional design (which Rx is supposed to enable). I also don't understand your comment about the `Subscribe` overload re-throwing exceptions it receives. It's not `Subscribe` that throws in the example, its `OnError`.

Comment: Subscriptions generally don't modify observables, and that's certainly not the case here. See addendum.